# Create a user input array, find the average of rows in the array, and list those averages in a new Array?

Tags: java, arrays

So, I'm having trouble on the bit where the averages need to be stored into an Array. I'm able to take input from the user for each student and so forth. I can then properly calculate the grade, but then it wont give me the array of averages. I kind of understand why it's happening, but I have no clue on how to fix it if i'm being honest. Ive hit the books, the professors slides, and google as much as I can.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGradeDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        

                    System.out.print("Enter a number of students: ");
                    int rows = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("Enter a number of scores: ");
                    int columns = input.nextInt();

                    double[][] gradesArray = new double[rows][columns];

                    

                    for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0 ; j<columns ; j++)
                        {
                            System.out.printf("Please enter score %d for the student %d: ", j + 1, i +1);
                            gradesArray[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    double rowSum = 0;
                    double [] scoreArray  = new double[columns];
                    for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0  ; j<columns ; j++)
                        {
                            rowSum = rowSum + gradesArray[i][j];
                            scoreArray[j] = (double)rowSum/columns;
                            
                        }
                        System.out.printf( "The average score for student %d is: " + (double)rowSum/columns + "%n", i+1 );
                        rowSum = 0;
                        
                                             
                }
                    
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scoreArray));
}
}
```

```
my output looks like, 

Enter a number of students: 5
Enter a number of scores: 2
Please enter score 1 for the student 1: 34
Please enter score 2 for the student 1: 65
Please enter score 1 for the student 2: 34
Please enter score 2 for the student 2: 76
Please enter score 1 for the student 3: 54
Please enter score 2 for the student 3: 23
Please enter score 1 for the student 4: 87
Please enter score 2 for the student 4: 65
Please enter score 1 for the student 5: 87
Please enter score 2 for the student 5: 56

The average score for student 1 is: 49.5
The average score for student 2 is: 55.0
The average score for student 3 is: 38.5
The average score for student 4 is: 76.0
The average score for student 5 is: 71.5

[43.5, 71.5] <- this should be the array, but I dont know what it is. Please go easy on me, its my first semester and I'm really struggling. Thanks for the help.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **exactly** what you ask for!

```
Arrays.toString(scoreArray)
```

prints the **contents** of your array. `scoreArray` has **two** entries, and those get printed, as `[43.5, 71.5]`.

In other words: your code does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thats not actually what I want though, im brand new to this and stumped. I want it to create an array displaying all the averages. I'm clueless, and confused on what route to take to do that, instead of what its actually doing.